# Can't Find Safari History File (Time Machine)

Tags: time-machine, migration-assistant

I am trying to restore my Safari history and saved passwords from a Time Machine backup on Mojave.

The history.db file, according to Apple's website, is supposed to be at ~Library/Safari.
However, that directory is not there. Where is it hiding?

Edit: I wonder if I did a complete restore from Time Machine (through Migration Assistant?) if everything would be restored.

Comment: There is a history.db file under ~Library/com.apple.internal.ck/history.db but I have no way of knowing if this is the Safari history file.

Comment: Where do you find the history file in your Mac directly (in the system you use, not in the backup)?

Comment: @nohillside: I just started using the (new hard drive-equipped) Mac and there is no ~/Library/Safari directory.  I did a search of hidden files and the only history.db file is in com.apple.internal.ck/history.db

Comment: Which specific path did you look at on the backup (there is no ~ there, so the ful path would be interesting).

Comment: I searched the entire drive for any files with the case insensitive name: history.db

Comment: Then it's maybe just not there? What is the content of `..../Users/YOURUSER/Library/Safari` in the latest backup (and maybe in one which is a few months old)?

Comment: There is no Safari directory.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking in the correct spot? The Safari directory gets created the first time a user starts the application.

Comment: I looked. It's not there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start Safari at least once to get the history database in `~/Library/Safari/History.db`.

You'll find it in the same place in your TimeMachine backup.

Comment: It's not in the Time Machine backup. Nor is it on the Mac, after starting up. Running Safari 12.1.2; Mojave 10.14.6. There should be at least a year's worth of history and passwords on the Time Machine backup.